# Sort rows based on columns?

Tags: r, csv, sorting, row, columnsorting

I have a csv in R which has the following table:

df1

| Start | Efficiency | Start | Efficiency | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9955 | 0 | 9955 | 25 | 5848 |
| 474909 | 0 | 474909 | 35 | 3948 |
| 90342 | 25 |  |  | 84384 |
| 94209 | 55 |  |  | 99393 |

I want to replace the false zero efficiencies corresponding to the start column with the correct efficiencies so that my final result can look like this:

df2

| Start | Efficiency | End |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9955 | 25 | 5848 |
| 474909 | 35 | 3948 |
| 90342 | 25 | 84384 |
| 94209 | 55 | 99393 |

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Start = c("9955", "474909", "90342", "94209"),
  Efficiency = c("0", "0", "25", "55"), 
  Start = c("9955", "474909"),
  Efficiency = c("25", "35"), 
  End = c("5848", "3948", "84384", "99393"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  Start = c("9955", "474909", "90342", "94209"),
  Efficiency = c("25", "35", "25", "55"),
  End = c("5848", "3948", "84384", "99393"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R doesn't like columns with same name hence the duplicate column names become `Start.1` and `Efficiency.1`. You can replace the 0 value with `NA` and use `coalesce`.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(across(contains('Efficiency'), na_if, 0)) %>%
  transmute(Start, Efficiency = coalesce(Efficiency, Efficiency.1))

#   Start Efficiency
#1   9955         25
#2 474909         35
#3  90342         25
#4  94209         55
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I have extra columns in df1 and this command deletes every other column and only keeps efficiency and start. Is there any way to keep the other non relevant columns as well>

Comment: Sure, use `mutate` instead of `transmute`.